# Running Google App Engine on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: python, google, sdk, google-app-engine

I recently switched from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. I'm new to all this.
So I have python 2.7.6 installed and I tried to get Google App Engine 
working, here: [Hello, World! - Python - Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld). How do I find the path to the Python SDK ?

Answer (score -1):

[Simple Tutorial](http://www.johnogrady.com/blog/2012/09/01/setup-google-app-engine-on-ubuntu/)

Here are the steps I followed to get GAE 1.7.1 working on Ubuntu 12.04.

open a terminal Ctr-t and make sure you are in the home directory.
create a project folder. (I used google_projects)
cd into the project folder
download GAE 1.7.1
unzip the file
delete the zip. (optional)
Here are the terminal commands for the steps above:

```
    cd ~
mkdir google_projects
cd google_projects
wget -O gae.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.6.zip
unzip gae.zip
rm gae.zip
```

Now its time to create the project and start the development server.

```
    cp -r google_appengine/new_project_template testapp
    python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py testapp
```

The first line simply copies and renames the new_project_template folder into google_proects as testapp. The last line starts the development server. You can stop it with Ctr-C.

With the development server up and running you can view testapp at localhost:8080. You should see "Hello world!".

Or you can do a diff way

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install appengine
```

Then install a given VERSION of the SDK:

```
appengine.py [--prefix=/path/where/to/install] VERSION
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks! It's working but I can't figure out how to start the app in this tutorial. Could you help me out please? http://imgur.com/tQ3p6fg
The tutorial is here https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs253/l-48230541/e-48689147/m-48727384 and I have to run the webapp given in the tutorial on port 8888 and I cant figure out how to do that